# Azure ML ops task to write a file in git repo

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to implement ml ops in azure. I am running a python script through azure cli task in devops. Though I can read files from the git folder but the py script is not able to generate the output csv in git. Strangely its also not giving any error.

I think the file is getting generated in the compute instance directory. How to instead write it to a git folder or any folder which I can see in the compute engine.

Comment: As per documentation we should get ./output and /logs folder .I can now output a file into./log folder but ./output is not getting created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation where python couldn't find the files that were supposed to exist in the root of the Azure ML project folder after deploying. After investigation, I realized that Azure ML invokes your scripting code from a different root folder.

Here is an example of an operation that reads from the relative path where your code exists:

```
    SCRIPT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(SCRIPT_DIRECTORY+'filename.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(dict_object, outfile)
```

You can then join to `SCRIPT_DIRECTORY`  the relative path of your git folder, before your output.

Alternatively, as per your comment "./output is not getting created", you can force it with:

`os.makedirs("./outputs", exist_ok=True)`

`exist_ok` (optional) : A default value `False` is used for this parameter. If the target directory already exists an `OSError` is raised if its value is `False` otherwise not. For value `True` leaves directory unaltered.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please clarify on the below line a bit
"You can then join to SCRIPT_DIRECTORY  the relative path of your git folder, before your output."

Comment: though again the script is running in my devops pipeline task without error but unable to see the output json.

Comment: I meant that you can then join the relative path of your git folder to SCRIPT_DIRECTORY like this: `SCRIPT_DIRECTORY + YOUR_GIT_FOLDER + 'filename.json'`

NOTE: I'm assuming you are running a script from your project folder (git), because SCRIPT_DIRECTORY will be the directory where your script is running. I hope this makes sense.

This should allow you to see the output json in the snapshot of your pipeline

Comment: I am runing the script from the root of my git repo. I am expecting the json to be in the root of the repo as well. should it look like  this? : SCRIPT_DIRECTORY + .\ + 'filename.json' (though its not working) .

Comment: Hi @Andy, in that case please do `SCRIPT_DIRECTORY + '/filename.json'`